# How would I create a scoped url for paperclip attachments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I have this (these) model(s)

```
Portfolio
-- PortfolioItem item
  -- Image image
     has_attachment :attachment
```

all with nice slugs and I would want the url of :attachment to reflect this organization, such as with a instance

```
photos/holiday_in_venice/ponte_vecchio (all slugs of the respective hierarchy)
```

would generate this url

```
photos(??)/holiday_in_venice(??)/:slug/:style.:extension
```

how would I access these antecessor objects during paperclip path/url creation?

currently I am only able to do

```
ponte_vecchio/small.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to create [custom interpolations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Interpolations). After that you are able define a `:url` and a `:path`.

Put a file called `paperclip.rb` in your `config/initializers/` folder and do something like this:

```
Paperclip.interpolates :portfolio_slug do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.portfolio_item.portfolio.title.parameterize
end

Paperclip.interpolates :portfolio_slug do |attachment, style|
  attachment.instance.portfolio_item.title.parameterize
end
```

After that you can use those interpolations like that:

```
has_attached_file :attachment, 
  :path=>":rails_root/public/photos/:portfolio_slug/:item_slug/:style.:extension",
  :url=>"/photos/:portfolio_slug/:item_slug/:style.:extension"
```

Comment: Thanks that did it! Even though, as I cannot really reutilize these interpolations in a different model, I guess I'd just make up one big :portfolio_image_path and have it all in one place...